For all $h\in \mathbb{R}\sim\{0\}$, two distinct tangents be drawn from the point $(2+h,3h-1)$ to the curve $y=x^3-6x^2-a+bx$ then $\frac{a}{b}=?$
If for all $h\in \mathbb{R}\sim\{0\}$, two distinct tangents can be drawn from the points $(2+h,3h-1)$ to the curve
$y=x^3-6x^2-a+bx$
then find value of $\frac{a}{b}$
My Attempt
If two distinct tangents are to be drawn from point $P\equiv(2+h,3h-1)\forall h\in\mathbb{R}\sim \{0\}$, then $P$ can be any point on the line $y=3x-7$ except $(2,-1)$.
By plotting the graph and visualizing in all possible ways I came to the conclusion that one of
the tangents must be the tangent line at the point of inflexion and that tangent line must be the line $y=3x-7$.
So, I proceeded further
$y'(x)=3x^2-12x+b$ and $y''(x)=6(x-2)$. So we have point of inflection at $x=2$.
Consequently, $y'(2)=b-12$ and $y(2)=2b-a-16$.
So equation of tangent line through the point of inflection is
$y=y(2)+y'(2)(x-2)$
i.e. $y=(b-12)x+8-a$
If this were to coincide with $y=3x-7$ then $b-12=3$ and $8-a=-7$ which give $a=b=15$  and so $\frac{a}{b}=1$ which is indeed the right answer.
Another observation is that now the equation of the curve is
$y=x^3-6x^2+15x-15$ and the point $(2,-1)$ lies on the curve
But how to explain this idea analytically or mathematically. Visualization would not count in an exam.

It should be exactly two tangents, no?

It would appear so. The question does say 'two distinct tangents'

Let $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+bx-a.$
The discriminant or resultant of the expression and its derivative wrt $t$ of $$y-f(t)-(f'(t)(x-t))$$
or
3*h-1-(t^3-6*t^2+b*t-a)-((3*t^2-12*t+b)*(h+2-t))

is given by the determinant of the five by five Sylvester matrix
$\begin{vmatrix}2&-3\,h-12&12\,h+24&-b\,h+a-2\,b+3\,h-1&0\\
0&2&-3\,h-12&12\,h+24&-b\,h+a-2\,b+3\,h-1\\
6&-6\,h-24&12\,h+24&0&0\\
0&6&-6\,h-24&12\,h+24&0\\
0&0&6&-6\,h-24&12\,h+24
\end{vmatrix}.$
Maybe not tractable by hand, but a CAS simplifies this to
216*(b*h-15*h+2*b-a-15)*(h^3+b*h-15*h+2*b-a-15)

The linear factor vanishes identically when $a=b=15$. With that the second factor reduces to $h^3$.

How were you able to simplify the Discriminant .

@Maverick I cheated by using a CAS
